# diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5

Tags: java, jsp

Tengo el siguiente código el cual muestra algunos productos en un combobox

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%

        List<String> productos = new ArrayList<>();
        productos.add("TV");
        productos.add("PC");
        productos.add("Stereo");
        productos.add("Iphone");

        %>

        <select>
            <%
                for (String p : productos)
                {
                    out.println("<option>" + p + "</option>");
                }

            %>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pero al ejecutarlo obtengo el siguiente error

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
>   PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
>     (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)<

Tengo la versión 8 de Java, la versión 4.1.1 de Glassfish y la ultima versión de Netbeans.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Usas maven en tu proyecto?

Comment: No, no uso Maven.

Comment: Bueno, por lo visto, tu proyecto está configurado para usar Java 5 para compilar y ejecutar. Revisa en las propiedades de tu proyecto, quizás en el IDE.

Comment: Esta usando el JDK 8.

Comment: Eso no dice el mensaje de error. Indica que se está usando Java 5 en tiempo de ejecución, por eso la excepción. Revisa nuevamente el mensaje de error: `Generated servlet error: source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release`.

Comment: Actualice la pregunta con las fotos donde me salen las opciones que mencionaba.

Comment: El error es con Glassfish. Probé ejecutar el proyecto con Apache y no tengo problemas.

Comment: Mira en la opción Run.

Comment: Encontre la solucion aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449012/exception-while-creating-list-on-jsp . Ambas respuestas solucionan mi problema.

Comment: No entiendo. Una solución te dice lo mismo que yo: revisa que tu proyecto esté configurado para Java 7 o superior. El otro te dice que evites usar el operador diamante que es propio de Java 7, con lo cual pierdes características de Java 6, 7, 8 y posiblemente de 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente use **Java** 5 pero el operador de diamante <> es la característica de **Java** 7. Entonces, hay dos soluciones:

Actualización a **Java** 7
No utilice el operador de diamantes <>

En lugar de declarar **ArrayList** como este:

```
List<String> productos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Declare **ArrayList** **Like**

```
List<String> productos = new ArrayList();
```

es decir, no use el <> en el lado derecho

Comment: En Java 5  se puede poner:  List<String> productos = new ArrayList<String>();  Lo que se agrego en Java 7 es la opción de no poner nada entre los <> del lado derecho.